# How can I most accurately associate Google Cloud Platform project costs with App Engine activity?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-stackdriver

I support a data management solution built on Google Cloud Platform. As our product matures, more and more teams and individuals are adopting it, meaning more people are storing and searching for data and racking up costs. We need to better understand how much each of these users/workflows are costing us so that we can eventually start charging them for using our services.

I already have billing data for the Google Cloud Platform project that our solution runs on exported to BigQuery. I've observed that 70-80 percent of our Google Cloud Platform bill for the project in question is attributed to App Engine (as a product), so I'm currently focusing on splitting App Engine costs. Here's a condensed view of App Engine costs for the project for one day (from BigQuery):

```
Row product     resource_type                   start_time              end_time                cost        usage_amount        usage_unit  
1   App Engine  Simple Searches                 2017-08-20 07:00:00 UTC 2017-08-20 08:00:00 UTC 0.1473      3946.0              requests     
2   App Engine  Flex Instance RAM               2017-08-20 07:00:00 UTC 2017-08-20 08:00:00 UTC 0.6816      3.710851743744E14   byte-seconds     
3   App Engine  Search Document Storage         2017-08-20 07:00:00 UTC 2017-08-20 08:00:00 UTC 0.505028    8.0921704558464E15  byte-seconds     
4   App Engine  Code and Static File Storage    2017-08-20 07:00:00 UTC 2017-08-20 08:00:00 UTC 0.0         5.96811043008E13    byte-seconds     
5   App Engine  Datastore Entity Writes         2017-08-20 07:00:00 UTC 2017-08-20 08:00:00 UTC 0.085804    67669.0             requests     
6   App Engine  Other Search Ops                2017-08-20 07:00:00 UTC 2017-08-20 08:00:00 UTC 0.0         1732.0              requests     
7   App Engine  Out Bandwidth                   2017-08-20 07:00:00 UTC 2017-08-20 08:00:00 UTC 0.273014    3.516638423E9       bytes    
8   App Engine  Datastore Read Ops              2017-08-20 07:00:00 UTC 2017-08-20 08:00:00 UTC 1.494541    2540902.0           requests     
9   App Engine  Search Document Indexing        2017-08-20 07:00:00 UTC 2017-08-20 08:00:00 UTC 0.05012     3.7645832E7         bytes    
10  App Engine  Datastore Storage               2017-08-20 07:00:00 UTC 2017-08-20 08:00:00 UTC 1.72891     2.7716055728688E16  byte-seconds     
11  App Engine  Flex Instance Core Hours        2017-08-20 07:00:00 UTC 2017-08-20 08:00:00 UTC 5.0496      345600.0            seconds  
12  App Engine  Task Queue Storage              2017-08-20 07:00:00 UTC 2017-08-20 08:00:00 UTC 0.0         5.14512E8           byte-seconds     
13  App Engine  Datastore Small Ops             2017-08-20 07:00:00 UTC 2017-08-20 08:00:00 UTC 0.0         16166.0             requests     
14  App Engine  Backend Instances               2017-08-20 07:00:00 UTC 2017-08-20 08:00:00 UTC 206.080588  1.4870202339153E7   seconds  
15  App Engine  Frontend Instances              2017-08-20 07:00:00 UTC 2017-08-20 08:00:00 UTC 1.35596     198429.126958       seconds
```

**Question 1:** By the way, for anybody familiar with Google Cloud Platform billing exports, an entry with `start_time` `2017-08-20 07:00:00 UTC` and `end_time` `2017-08-20 08:00:00 UTC` reflects costs incurred on 2017-08-20, not 2017-08-19, right?

Now, I understand that associating these App Engine costs with App Engine activity is not going to be an exact mapping–Google Cloud Platform does not bill per action, and there will be fixed and, I guess, shared resource costs (please correct me if I'm wrong!)–but I'd still like to get a sensible estimate. My first attempt involved checking [Google's logged estimated cost per request](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.logservice.logservice#google.appengine.api.logservice.logservice.RequestLog.cost). Therefore, I created a sink for the App Engine request logs and waited for the numbers to roll in. However, the total estimated cost for all requests on a given day using this approach is very low:

```
SELECT SUM(protoPayload.cost) AS cost_total
  FROM [my-data-management-solution:request_log.appengine_googleapis_com_request_log_20170820];
```

yields

```
Row cost_total   
1   3.2711573326337837
```

That barely accounts for 1.5% of the total App Engine costs!

**Question 2:** What `resource_type`(s) (from the Google Cloud Platform billing export) do the request log cost estimates correspond or contribute to?

About 95% of my App Engine costs are attributed to the Backend Instances `resource_type`. I did some cursory research into what they are (including [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jHpv6Sm1F8A) claiming that Google was moving away from the whole backend/frontend instances distinction). I assume (or may have read) that Google relies on whatever secret algorithms to spin up, shut down, and otherwise manage these instances. As such…

**Question 3 (the big question):** How can I get some visibility into how much individual user/workflow actions (limited to via App Engine is OK) contribute to total App Engine costs, or minimally App Engine Backend Instances costs, for a Google Cloud Project? Is it possible without something like regressing costs against user activity and creating an ML model? Is the idea of gaining insight into how this black box (both from the scaling and pricing perspectives) works or otherwise thinking that App Engine costs are somewhat directly correlated with user activity reasonable at all?

## Additional Information

1. Our data management solution uses its own concept of identity, and I'm not expecting Google to magically figure it out. I can currently link `request_log` items to users by parsing Stackdriver logs, and I'll work out the user-workflow associations or get them from another tool.
2. Just in case, is there anything to do some of this stuff out of the box? One StackOverflow comment mentioned [Potamus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8810125/how-to-estimate-hosting-services-cost-on-gae#comment25247497_8821907), but the repository is no longer available, and there's hardly any information out there about what it did to begin with.
3. If App Engine cost splitting isn't a big deal, how about for other products like Cloud Storage? It will be my next target, although the challenge of associating Cloud Storage costs (both the actual, potentially negligible, storage costs and the more expensive I/O costs) with App Engine activity seems even less reasonable at this point.

Comment: Did you ever come up with a satisfactory solution for this? I'm running into the same problem right now!

Answer (score 0):

Fully understand your interest in resource usage, hope this helps!

You can create (& manage) labels via the API resource manager in your GCP cloud console, this should provide clarity into resource usage. 
Label entities can be associated with teams/cost centers, users, environments, etc to gain clarity into resource usage. Linked resource provides further detail: [GCP_Using Labels](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/using-labels)

You can also create visual representations of billing data for further analysis using the export-to-BigQuery & Data Studio. The linked medium article is an awesome overview. [Medium_Visualizing GCP Billing Data using BQ and Data Studio](https://medium.com/google-cloud/visualize-gcp-billing-using-bigquery-and-data-studio-d3e695f90c08)

Cheers, 
Amber

Comment: Thank you for your response, Amber! I am aware of labels; another team within our organization uses labels to associate VMs with owners, and thus assigns cost them based on usage on their VMs. Unfortunately, I don't think it's so straightforward for App Engine and other shared resources, unless you can somehow label instances based on who's utilizing them (I guess dynamically?).